# How does ように work in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

練習してうまく話したり、書いたりすることができる**ように**なりたいです

I usually would interprete ように like that:
"to reach A, I do B"

Here I'm a bit confused because the verb なる follows the ように clause.
"To reach A, I wish to become."

Obviously this doesnt work. 
So are there any omitted phrases I'm missing or is ように in a different function here?

Comment: verb in potential form+ようになる = reach the point where one can verb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My easy way to interpret it is this.
ように means similar to X.
In your case, it is referring to the situation where you can talk and write well. So you want your current situation to become similar to the situation where you would be proficient in in talking and writing.

It has a slightly more broad meaning than just using なる by it self.

For example, you could use なる for saying I want to become a soccer player.
But you would use ようになりたい for saying I want to become able to play soccer.